# how to play livestream hls url on react native while the live stream is online

Tags: android, ios, react-native, webview, react-native-video

I'm relatively new to React Native and currently facing an issue displaying a live stream from "castr". They've provided an HLS URL, but I'm encountering difficulties in getting it to play. I've attempted using react-native-video and also experimented with webView, but haven't had success with either approach.

With webView, the default iOS video player appears, but it only shows a black screen. As for react-native-video, it simply won't open any URL.

Could someone please offer guidance or a solution to this problem? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Would you explain what problems did you faced while using react-native-video?

Try alternative video player package maybe such as https://github.com/razorRun/react-native-vlc-media-player which should play hls url.

Test if the video url is playing on the normal browser. If the video is playing on your browser then it might be related to how you implemented the code. Please post your code on how did you implement the video player on your app.